# Failed to run CloudKitAtlas (Cloudkit testing)

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I've downloaded the CloudKitAtlas sample code from Apple dated Sept 8. I did:

1. Setup the App ID
2. Enable the iCloud in Xcode capability

[image]

3. Setup the provisioning profile
4. Login to my iCloud Account in my Simulator (the different account from my developer account).

But the app crashes when I click the **Discoverability** in application. The error message is:

> An error occured in requestDiscoverabilityPermission:: CKError
>   0x7fd7f162c1c0: "Not Authenticated" (9/1004); "Account couldn't get
>   container scoped user id, no underlying error received"; Retry after
>   3.0 seconds>

Do I miss anything setting up the iCloud? Thanks

Comment: It's suddenly working now. Will it take a few hour to take effect? Or just because there was a server problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on my app. Deleting the application from the simulator and restarting it fixed the problem. Take a clean build if necessary

Also, make sure that you are logged in to iCloud in Settings app.

Comment: It happened a long time ago and I solved the problem by similar method. Anyway I'll accept your answer here! Thanks.